# trigonometry equilateral triangle

Tags: trigonometry

first of all, sorry for the lame question.

Having a starting point, A and a height (catet) of y, what's the formula to calculate x?
[image: Triangle]

Thank you, i don't have any trig basis.

Comment: An equilateral triangle can be cut into two 30-60-90 triangles. If $y$ is the altitude, then $x=\frac{y}{\sqrt 3}$. You can use the Pythagorean theorem for this: $y^2+x^2=4x^2$.

Comment: You don't have enough information here. You need either one angle or the base length.

Comment: @ja72,the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: ja72, it's an equilateral triangle so all the angles are 60 deg.

J.M. would you like to put that as an answer? so i can accept it? and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an equilateral triangle, each angle has measure 60°.  If you consider one of the smaller, right triangles formed by the altitude, the legs have length $y$ (the altitude) and $x$ (along the base) and the angle opposite the $y$ leg has measure 60°, so $$\tan 60°=\frac{y}{x}.$$  Since $\tan 60°=\sqrt{3}$, $$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: One thing I find problematic about this is that it assumes $\tan 60^\circ=\sqrt{3}$ rather than taking the opportunity to show how that fact is derived from the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I was going off having "trigonometry" in the title; having your solution as well is certainly worthwhile (and +1 there).

Answer (score 3):

Use the Pythagorean theorem.  The length of each side of the triangle is $2x$, so you have a right triangle (either the left half or the right half of the equilateral triangle) in which the hypotenuse has length $2x$ and one leg has length $x$.  The height must therefore be
$$
y=\sqrt{(2x)^2-x^2} = \sqrt{4x^2-x^2}=\sqrt{3x^2}=x\sqrt{3}.
$$